# HTML5 Web SQL Database API Relative Path

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, web-sql

Can we create/read SQLite format 3 in the same directory with HTML5 that implements Web SQL Database instead of storing it in default location (~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default)?

[HTML5 Web SQL Database API](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm)